# get match percentages between two objects by parameters

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to create a program that will automate a process that i am doing manually today.
I apologize if the solution seems to be easy i just don't want to think about new algorithm specially for my problem because i am sure that someone already thought about it.
My Scenario is this:
I have candidates list that are looking for jobs and I have jobs list.
For each candidate I know the following requirements of the job that he is searching for. like:

1. Salary
2. Location of the Job
3. Company Size (Big / Small)

In the manual process what i do is to match between those candidate's requirements parameters to the job's requirements parameter and "return" the jobs that seems to fit to the candidate (it doesn't have to be a completely match).
Of course i am considering candidate's requirement is "nice to have" or "must have".

I am searching for an algorithm that returns a fit percentage between each candidate to each job.
Can someone please point me to a any name of matching algorithm like this.

Thanks

Comment: Assign points to fitting parameters according to whatever scale you are using by hand now, take the sum of all points and divide by the total number of points achievable, then decide on a threshold of points the match needs to have in order to be considered? For deal-breaker situations (like "must be located within the US" for jobs that are in Papa New Guinea), you can just add a very small negative value (meaning something like -10000) so it cancels out any positive values contributing to the overall score to ensure the score stays below the acceptance threshold.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to convert every object to a *vector in a 3-D space* and then find the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the two vectors (objects).

- First, assign **salary**, **location** and **size** to *x*, *y* and *z* axis, respectively.
- Then map the properties to `[0, 1]` interval of the axis.

For example, if your min **salary** is 1'000, and max salary is 10'000, then you would map:

- $ 1'000 -> 0 on the *x* axis,
- $ 10'000 -> to 1 on the *x* axis.

Mapping **locations** is hard, but let's say you have a map grid, and you assign a value to each patch of the grid according to geo position - closer ones have similar values. For example, US states provide us with a good example:

- New York -> 1.0 on the *y* axis,
- New Jersey -> 0.99 on the *y* axis,
- ...
- California -> 0.1 on the *y* axis.

Map **company sizes** something like:

- start-up -> 0.2 on the *z* axis,
- ...
- multinational -> 1.0 on the *z* axis.

So, to give an example: **John** wants a salary of 9.000, wants a job in New York, and wants to work in a start-up company. His vector in 3D space would be `[0.82, 1.00, 0.1]`. 
**Peter** wants a salary of 5.500, wants a job in New Jersey, and wants to work in a really big company - `[0.5, 0.99, 0.8]`. And at last, **Mike** wants a salary of 8.000, a job in California, and a start-up too - `[0.73, 0.1, 0.1]`.

According to formula for Euclidean distance in 3D space:

```
d(a, b) = sqrt((a1-b1)^2 + (a2-b2)^2 + (a3 - b3)^2)

Distance between John and Peter is: d(J, P) = 0.77
Distance between John and Mike is:  d(J, M) = 0.90
```

So the conclusion would be that John and Peter are closer than John and Mike.

One more thing you could do is to bring in some constants to each axis to emphasize the importance of it (location is more important than company size, for example) so in the formula you could do something like:

```
d(a, b) = sqrt((a1-b1)^2 + (C*a2 - C*b2)^2 + (a3 - b3)^2), where C = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
similiarity(A,B) = 1 / (1 + (distance(A,B) / unit))
```

**Case where distance is 0:**

```
similarity(A,A)
= 1 / (1 + (distance(A,A) / unit))
= 1 / (1 + (0 / unit))
= 1 / (1 + 0)
= 1.0
~ 100 %
```

**Case where distance is infinite:**

```
similarity(A,Z)
= 1 / (1 + (distance(A,Z) / unit))
= 1 / (1 + (infinity / unit))
= 1 / infinity
= 0.0
~ 0 %
```

**Code:**

```
JobComparison* compare (Job a, Job b)
{

    // define units based on measurement
    double unit1 = 1000.0;
    double unit2 = 100.0;
    double unit3 = 10.0;

    // calculate distance
    double d1 = abs(a.salary - b.salary);
    double d2 = distance(a.location, b.location);
    double d3 = abs(a.companySize - b.companySize);

    // calculate similiarity
    double p1 = 1 / (1 + (d1 / unit1));
    double p2 = 1 / (1 + (d2 / unit2));
    double p3 = 1 / (1 + (d3 / unit3));

    return new JobCompare(p1, p2, p3);

}
```

---

```
public class JobCompare
{
  public:
    double salarySimiliarity;
    double locationSimiliarity;
    double companySimiliarity;
}

public class Job
{
  public:
    double salary;
    Location location;
    double companySize;
}
```